# Easy way to make LAN on iPad/iPhone via bluetooth or wireless

Tags: ios, sockets, networking, cocos2d-iphone

I want to make a simple LAN by using one(iPad/iPhone) as a host and another one as an client.

Do anyone have a simple code to sending datas via LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth won't be easy unless you're using [Game Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html), but maybe consider using Bonjour Networking for your server and client functionality?

[Here's a tutorial I found that explains how to write a Bonjour *Server*](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/bonjour_network_server_for_iphone) for iOS.  That'd be a good place to start.  [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29) is a relatively straightforward method of doing network on Apple devices.

Comment: You can use them together if you want.  I found [this blog entry](http://maniacdev.com/2011/01/cocos2d-and-gamekit-multiplayer-gameplay-example/) which pointed to [this game kit data send / receive example project](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/01/game-kit-data-sendreceive-demo-project/).